# Compare java Date to sql TIMESTAMP in the same timezone

Tags: java, sql, timezone

I need to compare between `userCurrentDate` to a list of options.

The options is a table in the database that contain time attribute (definition: TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE. in oracle). Each option have his time zone.

The `userCurrentDate` (definition Date. in java)  is a parameter that hold the user time and date with offset. The user can be from all over the world, so each user is in different time zone.

I need to compare between the user current **date**  to the options **date**.
So i need to get this 2 parameters in the same time zone.

How can i get this 2 parameters in the same time zone, in **SQL**?

I tried to get them in GMT, so i can get them in the same base, like this:

```
trunc(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(o.time)) = trunc(sysdate)
```

But its not a good solution.

So, i need to get them in the same timezone. how can i get that in an SQL command (or other solution)?

Comment: I believe the At TIME ZONE function is what you want, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216832/querying-oracle-timestamp-with-timezone

Comment: Please be aware that Date objects don't handle timezones. It keeps track of time as milliseconds passed since 01/01/70 in GMT only. You might want to use Calendar if you need to have some time based logic in your app.

Comment: @Grove, Please be aware that i wrote that the useCurrentDate hold the user time and date with **offset**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem with at time zone oracle function.
used:

```
to_timestamp_tz(to_char(CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'GMT') AT TIME ZONE o.time AS DATE)
```

and compare it to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need this conversion? What version of Oracle and Oracle JDBC do you have?

Did you try just binding your `userCurrentDate` and executing SQL, like this:

```
connection.prepareStatement("select * from options o where o.time = ?")
    .setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(userCurrentDate.getTime())
    .executeQuery();
```

I've tested this with `ojdbc14.jar` and Oracle 10g, and it works fine.

Since `Date` and `Timestamp` data types do not have any time zone information within them, you shouldn't actually care about matching time zones with DB values as long as:

1. You don't need your DB values to actually have *specific* time zone. When you insert some value into the column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, JDBC driver uses your local time zone.
2. You don't need to *display* the original time zone in your Java program, since as I said before `Date` / `Timestamp` types do not have that information in them.

As long as you just need to match your Java `Date` objects to DB values, you should be fine without any conversion.

Also, please check this comprehensive article on the subject: [[How To] Handle Oracle TimeStamp with TimeZone from Java](http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/11/02/how-to-handle-oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-from-java/)

Comment: In my code, they have  time zone. this time zone is important to my data base. o.time is a "list" and i need to compare each one of them to ?